# Incorrect syntax near the keyword else in stored procedure

Tags: sql, procedure

```
create proc login
    (@id int out,
     @email varchar(30),
     @passsword varchar(30),
     @type varchar(30) out)
as
begin
    select 
        @id = id, @type = type 
    from 
        registration 
    where 
        email = @email 
        and password = @password

    return 0
end
else
begin
    return 1
end
```

Comment: What is this procedure supposed to do?

Comment: I think you need `if` - the `else` is making no sense here. Please do some reading first - you didn't even ask a question here.

Comment: its a login procedure can you please edit it with if ,i tried so hardly

Comment: Always encrypt passwords.  *Never* store a plaintext password!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you are looking for this:

```
create procedure usp_login (
    @email varchar(30),
    @passsword varchar(30),
    @id int output,
    @type varchar(30) output
) as
begin
    set @id = NULL;

    select @id = id, @type = type
    from registration
    where email = @email and password = @password;

    return (case when @id is null then 0 else 1 end);
end;
```

Some notes:

- Your code suggests that you are using unencrypted passwords.  That is the first thing you need to learn how to fix.
- `else` -- as mentioned in the comments -- requires an `if`.
- When you mix input and output arguments, I prefer to make the `output` arguments the last arguments.  This is a matter of preference.  However, I think it is good practice to keep all inputs together and all outputs together -- unless you have a good reason.
- End your statements with semicolons.
- The use of return values from stored procedures can actually be a best practice.  However, it is not necessary.